# 'RequestSite' object has no attribute 'root_page'

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, wagtail

I have an issue where trying to set up wagtail with nginx and gunicorn. Running the django server on a gunicorn socket fails and get a 502 error at 'website.com/'. but when I execute manage.py runserver on localhost I get 'RequestSite' object has no attribute 'root_page' at 'website.com/local' My settings are below. What am I doing wrong?

NGINX

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mywebsite.com;
   keepalive_timeout 5;

   location /static/ {
     alias /home/user/static/;
   }

   location /media/ {
    alias /home/user/media/;
   }

   location /local/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
   }

   location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
   }
}
```

GUNICORN

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn 
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn.pid
User=user
Group=user
EnvironmentFile={{etcdir}}/gunicorn.env
WorkingDirectory={{projdir}}/
ExecStart={{projdir}}/venv/bin/gunicorn --config {{etcdir}}/gunicorn.conf.py --chdir /home/user/project project.wsgi:application
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
workers = 2
pythonpath = '/home/user/venv/bin/python3'
syslog = True
bind = ['unix:/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.sock','127.0.0.1:8000',]
umask = 0
loglevel = "info"
user = "user"
group = "user"
```

PRODUCTION.PY

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]

SITE_ID = 1
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/user/media"
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/static'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASS'],
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I am using:

- Python 3.7
- Django 2.2.17
- Wagtail 2.7.4

Answer (score 1):

Have you possible recently updated wagtail? Part of the 2.9 upgrade release notes, have a look at this for more info - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/releases/2.9.html#sitemiddleware-and-request-site-deprecated

Comment: django 2.2.17 is supported by wagtail 2.7.4. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging I found I had miss-matching ptyhon environment vars.

The django and wagtail versions were compatible but the virtualenv was made in python 3.5 and had a symlink to a later installed python3.7. And a python3.7 wagtail was calling a different older django on the 3.5 interpreter. This is why when I pip freeze in python3.7 they had the correct versions but they were calling the wrong ones.

To solve this I deleted the old virtual env and made a new one from python3.7 and re pip install dependencies everything. I could not update django on 3.7 because it required the new secrets package in python 3.6.